# How do I make Vorpal output a description of a command

Tags: javascript, function, this, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

console.log("Are you sure you wish to investigate the murder?")

vorpal
.delimiter('grey9nr$')
.show();

vorpal.command('Yes')
.action(function(args, cb){
const self = this;
this.prompt({
type: 'confirm',
name: 'continue',
default: false,
message: 'That sounds like a really bad idea. Continue?',
}, function(result){
if (result.continue) {
self.log('Good move.');
cb();
} else {
self.log('Your life is in danger. We will contact you with more information in due course.');
app.destroyDatabase(cb);
}
});
});
```

Which results in the following:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to be able to define what yes means so the player knows what answering 'yes' will do, or require them to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either pass the description as the second parameter of the `command()` function, or explicitly set it with `description()`.

Either

```
vorpal.command('Yes', `These words will show up in the help')
.action(function(args, cb){
...
```

or

```
vorpal.command('Yes')
.description('`These words will show up in the help'')
.action(function(args, cb){
...
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll add it into the site soon.